# Update for an iPhone app not showing up in available updates

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have pushed a fourth update(1.4) for my iphone application, but the update is not showing up in available updates. Its been 2 days since its been 'Ready for Sale' so i don't think its related to 24hrs caching period.
All my previous updates have worked well.

If anybody else has faced the issue, kindly let me know.

Comment: I would try to use the Contact Us link on your iTunes Connect page. I have used this a couple of times in the past to contact the app team, and they have seemed to be pretty responsive.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. I'm getting the update on my device but most of the clients said they are not getting any type of update from App Store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just submitted another update and it worked fine.
Don't know the reason though.

Comment: I don't want to upload a new version. Why update is appearing only for some users.? Is that any kind of app store error?